# Eclipse: Break at address "0xXXXX" with no debug information available, or outside of program code

Tags: c, eclipse, debugging, usb, firmware

I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ke4oK.png) message when I am to run the debugger on Softconsole. Is there any specific setting I should set to avoid this error message? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should set a breakpoint at the beginning of your program, and step through until you can narrow down what function(s) or data is causing the break.

Comment: Hi, Yes, it breaks first at the main, which is the initial start of the program.

Comment: Then your debugger is set to automatically stop at the beginning of the program, to allow you to step through from the beginning.   There is no bug, and you just need to press "Continue" to keep running your program.

Comment: @abelenky it can happen even with "continue" enabled

Answer (score 0):

If you will use the recommended "workspace.examples" or base your workspace on a copy of the "workspace.empty" (depending on the version of SoftConsole this can happen automatically), then you will not see the issue.